# Display AutoCompleteTextView description searching for id

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

As the title suggest, I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` and a table with two columns (ID, Description). I want to be able to input the ID and show the list of the Descriptions matching that, for example:

```
ID     Description
1111   Soda
1112   Beans
1113   Flour
```

If I type 111 in the `AutoCompleteTextView`, it has to show the three items.

The query is working, everything is working, but because the `AutoCompleteTextView` needs the text to show suggestions, it doesn't show anything when typing 111.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()
```

Thanks anyway!